# Volley API 23 compatibility

Tags: android, android-volley, apache-httpclient-4.x, android-6.0-marshmallow

When Apache http client was deprecated in Android Marshmallow (API23), Volley was not compatible with API23. Many patches were submitted and workarounds were suggested.

Now after one year, what's the official status on the issue?

Comment: If I know correctly, unfortunately Google has not changed this issue. I have customized Google's volley (as a module in my project) and uploaded to https://github.com/ngocchung/volleynoapache, please take a look. Please note that, however, it has not been fully tested for all cases. I have just tested with simple GET, POST requests.

Comment: @BNK is right. another option I have done myself and actively supporting is https://github.com/apptik/jus, based on Volley but supports many more options and fixes.